# PTIJ: Harem d'rabbeinu Gershom

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

My friend said he wouldn't marry multiple wives even though [it is allowed](http://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/parsha/committed-to-rabbeinu-gershom/2014/09/04/) because he didn't want to be "put in a harem." Personally, I don't see what's so bad about being put in a harem. I actually think I would like it. So what is so bad about a harem-- or, more likely, what is my friend's problem??

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I'm not sure that everyone got the question - it was about (c)harem, right?

Comment: @Uber_Chacham Yup. How could I make it clearer? I thought it would be obvious...

Comment: I did too, but these other answers seem to have missed it

Comment: You wouldn't mind being in a harem!? I sincerely hope you're joking.

Comment: @ezra It's Purim Torah, so yeah, I am

Comment: The very idea of harem d'rabbeinu gershon still has me laughing. (I wish that was the title...)

Comment: If Rabbeinu Gershom had a harem, I guess it can't be too bad...

Comment: He did, actually, and that's what caused the whole story that ended up with him making the charem

Comment: Hey! I'm a New Yorker! Why are you making fun of Harlem??

Comment: @DanF I didn't mean it like that!...

Comment: @Uber_Chacham, SAH, I corrected to Rabbeinu Gersho**m**, if there was some joke that I missed (about Gershon vs. Gershom), SAH, please rollback.

Comment: You're right; it was my mistake first

Comment: @Uber_Chacham Sorry; I never know which one it is, so I"ve taken to using Gershon and Gershom interchangeably (based partly on some discussion that they are actually the same)

Comment: @SAH - Why are you apologizing - it was my mistake, and I put it in your head

Answer (score 4):

Because unless his wives are in harem too, he can't have anything to do with them

Answer (score 3):

Because once someone is in a (c)harem, they have to walk around barefoot all the time. Those extra wives get really makpid on mud and dirt.

Answer (score 3):

He wouldn't want to be in a harem because that's where they put all the gross stuff!

[Shmuel 1 15:9](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t08a15.htm)

> וְכָל-הַמְּלָאכָה נְמִבְזָה וְנָמֵס, אֹתָהּ הֶחֱרִימוּ.
>
> And all the junk and the gross stuff, they put in the harem.

Answer (score 1):

I never visited a harem, so I can't comment from personal experience. But, from my understanding of the Megilla's description, it's a very smelly place.

[Esther 2:12](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4276&st=&pgnum=23) says that before the girls would visit King Achashevrosh (the story sounds like the Persian version of "The Bachelor", BTW) they would steep themselves for 12 months in spices, perfumes and all types of cosmetics.

So, if your friend likes overly perfumed smelling girls, he would find the harem a nice place. Some people, like me, are allergic to perfumes, so they would find being a harem sickening.

Comment: I heard it was only olive oil. How that made the girls extremely beautiful I don't know. But at least your sensitive nose would be ok